# Large, huge or big communities?

Tags: word-choice

When I talk about many people, like *community,* what should I use?

- A large community
- A huge community
- A big community

In my native language (German), we use just one word for that: *groß*. What is the difference in English?

Comment: In German there is also *riesig*. Google Translate uses that to translate *huge*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=large,big,huge&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) NGram, *large* is far more common overall than *big* and *huge* put together, so in any context where you're not sure which word to use, treat *large* as the default.

Also note that parents normally introduce their children to *big* before *large* (probably because it seems phonetically simpler and more distinctive). So in later life people may see *big* as slightly childish/informal, where *large* appears more "grown-up"/formal.

I suggest avoiding *huge* unless you really want to emphasise *abnormally large*. But as @barbara says, there are many alternatives in that case (*enormous, gigantic, vast* etc.). It's also worth noting that in casual speech, people often use "quirky/unusual" alternatives such as *humungous, ginormous, thumping*. It's best to avoid those unless you're in company where you notice others doing it.

---

The only "rule" I can think of to help decide when it's better to choose *big* over *large* is that *big* becomes more likely in contexts which are more metaphorical (as opposed to "literal", when you're talking about the physical size of something).

Thus, there's nothing to choose between a *big man* and a *large man*, because that's simply the literal sense. But in...

> *That was **big** of him* (he did something noble/generous).
>   *It was a **big** disappointment* (it was very disappointing).
>   *He's just **bigging** himself up* (he's trying to make himself appear more important than he really is).

... *large* would never be used. With OP's specific noun *community*, the metaphoric "stretch" isn't actually very great (large/big!), and there's really nothing to choose between *large* and *big*.

Of course, there will be plenty of exceptions to my above "rule" (as in the relatively recent BrE slang [*giving it large*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22giving%20it%20large%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22were%20giving%20it%20large%22&oq=%22were%20giving%20it%20large%22&gs_l=serp.3...22904.23756.0.24187.5.5.0.0.0.1.130.425.3j2.5.0...0.0...1c.1.2.serp.IthpLrDTGE8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.d2k&fp=16bcd31c3a821159&biw=1442&bih=889), being noisily aggressive). So just think of it as a "slight tendency".

Answer (score 8):

I think all of the examples sound like good English, although the quantity expressed is slightly different.

A large community [of people] and a big community [of people] both seem to reflect a good sized quantity, while a huge community seems to imply that it is much larger when compared to other sizes.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, I don't believe there is a big (sic) difference except that *large community* is probably the most commonly used, and *huge community* the least commonly — but it doesn't sound odd. *Huge* is a little informal, so you probably wouldn't hear it used in the news or read it in formal publications too often.

Comment: Informal, and meaning bigger than big or large.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the noun from "community" to "group", then "big group" and "large group" mean (to me) the same thing, although "large" is a bit more formal.  A "huge group" would imply something larger than a "large group".  (To get even larger, there are "enormous" and "gigantic", though those terms are used more often to describe objects rather than collections of things or beings.)