# How to find the right adjective to a word?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

When I am writing an article, from time to time, I am not sure which adjective to use when describing that **something is significant (or insignificant)**.

- My current problem is: *significant **advance*** in satellite communication. Is there any commonly used adjective for that? (large advance, vast advance, big advance,..)

Also there was a similar question: [Large, huge or big
   communities?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8/large-huge-or-big-communities)

In general, are there rules regarding this matter? Or the only thing what one can do is to get **used to the right combination** and search on web-pages like [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+advance%2Chuge+advance%2Cextensive+advance%2Cvast+advance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) or [Corpus of historical American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/) ?

Comment: The proper adjective usually depends on context: topic, audience, register, spoken or written, formal or informal, etc. If you're asking about what people normally say in a particular field, that's different: there are standard terms & phrases in the literature. There is no absolute standard for any brand of conversational English, except in set phrases that nobody changes. There are dialect & regional & local & generational differences, however. Not very helpful, but your question isn't very specific.

Comment: actually it answers pretty well, according what you say: _there are no rules on that, different fields uses different phrases_  I will try to make it more specific even though

Comment: significant = major//a major advance in x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Significant* means *meaningful*; it says nothing about magnitude. A small advance may be significant:

> Gene analysis based on work done by the publicly funded Human Genome Project may have moved science a small but significant step closer to finding a better treatment for Alzheimer's disease.

By the same token, a large advance may be insignificant:

> This tonnage represent a very large advance in airborne volume, but is still insignificant relative to over-the-road volume.

So if you mean *significant*, write *significant* - don't replace it with *big* or *large* or *huge*. If however you are talking about magnitude, let usage guide you; consulting a corpus is a very good idea. (But at the BYU site you want COCA, *Corpus of Contemporary American Usage*, or BNC, *British National Corpus*, rather than COHA.) *Large* and *big* vary idiomatically; *huge*, however, signifies a much greater magnitude than either of those, *amazingly large*, and in formal usage will suggest you are speaking hyperbolically unless you can substantiate the choice.

Comment: Significant = major, which is used quite a lot.